# Execute a Python application from a Joomla website, taking input and producing an output on the website

Tags: php, python, bash, joomla

I have a website created entirely on Joomla. To access this website, users have to enter username and password (in other words, is not "public").

I also have a Python application that take three input values and produce an output.

I would like to "connect" the website with the application, in a way that when a user clicks on a button, the python application executes, take the three input values from the database of the website and show the output on the joomla website.

To make things easier, I thought that instead of executing a Python application straight from the Joomla website, it would be easier to execute a bash script that runs the application.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the Python application run slowly enough that it would need to be run as a background process? If so, a job server would be good here e.g. Gearman.

Comment: seriously, save yourself some pain and put your python app on an internal webapp (like django/pyramid/flask/...etc) whatever.  Just hit your app with a rest/soap call and get a response back.